# How to get all properties of type alias into an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Given this type alias:

```
export type RequestObject = {
    user_id: number,
    address: string,
    user_type: number,
    points: number,
};
```

I want an array of all its properties, e.g:

```
['user_id','address','user_type','points']
```

Is there any option to get this? I have googled but I can get it only for interface using following package

https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You cannot do this easily, because of [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types)

Typescript types only exist at compile time. They do not exist in the compiled javascript. Thus you cannot populate an array (a runtime entity) with compile-time data (such as the `RequestObject` type alias), unless you do something complicated like the library you found.

#### Workarounds

1. code something yourself that works like the library you found.
2. find a different library that works with type aliases such as `RequestObject`.
3. create an interface equivalent to your type alias and pass that to the library you found, e.g.:

```js
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

export type RequestObject = {
    user_id: number,
    address: string,
    user_type: number,
    points: number,
}

interface IRequestObject extends RequestObject {}

const keysOfProps = keys<IRequestObject>();

console.log(keysOfProps); // ['user_id', 'address', 'user_type', 'points']
```